# Query on DaysOfWeek using Entity Framework for an Access database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ms-access

I have an Access database that I am querying using Entity Framework (v6.4.0). Now I need to get the last date for a given Day of the week (e.g. last date entered for a Friday).

The SQL query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT MAX(Datum) AS LastDate 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE WEEKDAY(Datum) = WEEKDAY(dateToCheck)
```

Here `dateToCheck` contains the day I am looking for. But I can't translate it to EF for MS Access. I have tried `SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", date)` but it only works for SQL, not for Access. So the following code doesn't work for Access database

```cs
await context.MyTable.Where(x => SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", x.Datum) == (int)dateToCheck.DayOfWeek)
                     .MaxAsync(x => x.Date)
```

It throws [NotSupportedException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notsupportedexception?view=netframework-4.8) with message:

> The specified method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DatePart(System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' on the type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.

Is there a function that works for Access DB?

NOTE: This is an old MS Access 2003 database if that makes any difference. And I'm using JetEntityFrameworkProvider as data provider.

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: @DavidG updated the question with EF version

Comment: Which data provider do you use?

Comment: @GertArnold JetEntityFrameworkProvider

Comment: I think the best approach is to add a query to the database that adds a Weekday column to "MyTable" so you can filter on that column.

Comment: @GertArnold changing the database is not an option. I just consume the data, can't modify the schema.

Comment: A query is not a schema change, but anyway, then I think this can't be done. I've even experimented a bit with db functions libraries (like [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Functions)), but they translate function calls with block quotes. Access doesn't "understand" `[Weekday]`.

Comment: Access understands [Weekday] when I pass it as a "string query". I have a suspision that the problem is with JetEntityFrameworkProvider, it probably can't translate Weekday for Access.

Comment: No, it can't just like that. But the mentioned library can make it translatable by adding it as a function to the DbContext. I tried with Access 2016 which didn't swallow the square brackets. Maybe older versions do. You could try your luck.